# Intellij IDEA diff file compare (without VCS)

Tags: intellij-idea

I heavily rely on git in my workflow. However, I do not use IDEA's integration since using the shell and aliases has always been faster. Now I noticed that when enabling the VCS-support, there is an `Compare with same repository`, `Compare with branch`, `Compare with ...`.

Now I wonder if it is possible to merge a diff file (with all the <<<<<<<). Even when enabling the VCS-support, IDEA does not seem to support that.

Does anyone know if (and how) merging a diff file with IDEA is possible?

Comment: What sort of file do you mean? A patch/diff file, with just the changes to be applied to another file(s), or a file that is in conflict with another, with both versions of the conflicted code in there, but separated by <<<<<< etc?

Comment: @MattGibson I mean the conflict file, containing both versions separated by <<<<<< (btw, is there a name for this kinda file?)

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? You are talking about output like from diff3 http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Conflict

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if that's what you ask. But it's possible to select two files in the project's file browser and compare them by clicking 'Compare Two Files' in the context menu. If you do so the diff/merge dialog will open with same possibilities as when opened with VCS related commands.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kai, that's exactly what i've been searching for

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just enable the IDEA git integration (to be able to do diffs in IDEA) and keep using the shell for the other git commands. I have worked that way with both Git and Perforce, and IDEA works fine that way.

Comment: even with the git integration enabled I've found no way to merge files ( containing <<<<<<).